# Spring Boot PostMapping deserialize Long array

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I'm trying to deserialize a list of Long values:

```
{
    "ids": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

With the following Method:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/export")
    public ResponseEntity<SomeDto> exportCsv(@RequestBody Long[] ids) {
        // Some methods
        return ResponseEntity.ok(someDto);
    }
```

But I keep getting the following error: `JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type Long`. The Error is the same using List<Long>, just for ArrayList<Long>.

I've tried it with `@JsonDeserialize(using = NumberDeserializers.LongDeserializer.class)`, but it seems either it doesn't work or I'm using it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With json object you try to send, spring assume it's an object with a member field `ids`. If you want to attach directly to a list send the following json as body:

```
[5, 6, 8]
```

This will work for:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/export")
public ResponseEntity<SomeDto> exportCsv(@RequestBody Long[] ids) {
...
}
```

and

```
@PostMapping(value = "/export")
public ResponseEntity<SomeDto> exportCsv(@RequestBody List<Long> ids) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The request body above represents a POJO class with `ids` as a property like below

```
public class Body {

  private Long[] ids;
  //getters and setters

 }
```

And then use this POJO as RequestBody

```
public ResponseEntity<SomeDto> exportCsv(@RequestBody Body body)
```